# [UNITY 3D VR]Why does my image look like it has weird noise when I set it as texture on runtime, but not when set as default?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I tried this for six hours and I have no clue.  I used a jpg file as a material.  When I set it as a material in my project, it's all good, but if I download the same file via http and set it as the material's main texture, it has weird noise .  if I stand really close , the noise is gone.
When I convert the file into png format, I see the same result.  It's also the same result when I change the aspect ratio, and when I use a different shader.  Do you have any idea what causes the discrepancy, and what I can do to get a consistent result without noise?

```
MeshRenderer textileBoxRender = textileImageShowBox.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            Texture myTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
            Debug.Log("Downloag Texture Suceeful!!!");
            textileBoxRender.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", myTexture);
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

this take  me over 20 hours ! it's mipmap issue! when u import into unity , it will auto check mipmap option , but if u download from http , it won't generate mipmap

```
Texture2D tx1 = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;
            var tx2 = new Texture2D(tx1.width, tx1.height);
            tx2.SetPixels(tx1.GetPixels());
            tx2.Apply(true);
            HeroObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tx2;
```

problem solved!